# For sencha app build , do we need to include all js files related to view in main.js(portal.js)?

Tags: extjs, build, sencha-cmd

I am using sencha cmd 6 for building my application.
my folder structure is

- classic

  - src

    - model
    - view

      - account
      - jobs
      - portal

        - portal.js
    - controller
    - store

production build process execution is successful but when i load that build its giving .js file not found error.
So i include all js files in folder structure into main js portal.js then .js error is removed and build works.

But i dont want to include all these list of files in one single js, so can we skip the js include part from portal.js and use any property or attribute to include all js files ?

Comment: Which .js file not found error are you getting? All ExtJS files are automatically linked together so there is no need for such thing, but when you are including some extra files you should "mention' them in the app.json file under section js: []

Comment: Yeah, it should link all js files automatically, but after build it shows me error in index.html file ".js"  not found , no specific file name mentioned.
I found another solution for that. " I included all the controllers and model path in application.js file in app folder"  so controller calls all view files and build works. Is this correct way to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify with `*` like `'Ext.chart.*'` in requires section of Ext.app.Application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks , it was folder structure problem . Included require controllers in js files  so that it will link all js file